# how to dir function input folder file through script output folder using php

Tags: php

How I can take files from input folder to output folder?

What i have done i mentioned it below

```
    <?php

    require_once 'dir_function.php';

    //file Path folder name
    $dir = "InputFolder";

    $diro = "OutputFolder";

    //Call directory function
    $filesArr = Load_Resource($dir);   

    $filesArr[0] = "registered_column1.csv";
    $filesArr[1] = "registered_column2.csv";
    $filesArr[2] = "registered_column3.csv";
    $filesArr[3] = "registered_column4.csv";
    $filesArr[4] = "registered_column5.csv";

    echo "I want" . "<br>" . $filesArr[0] . "<br>" . $filesArr[1] . "<br>" . $filesArr[2] . "<br>" . $filesArr[3] . "<br>" . $filesArr[4];
```

Comment: please try to clarify your question. Do you simply wish to MOVE files from `InputFolder` to `OutputFolder` or COPY? Or is it something else you wish to do?

Comment: i want to move files one folder to another

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename()` function : [PHP function rename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```
foreach($filesArr  as $file)
{
    rename($dir . '/' . $file, $diro . '/' . $file) ;
}
```

Note that the file will be overwritten if it already exists in the output directory.